# Date and time for log files different to `date`, `timezone` etc

Tags: server, log, time, timezone

On a Ubuntu 14.04 vps, my timezone is set to UTC/GMT.

```
root@Ubuntu:/# date 
Fri Mar 11 13:36:56 GMT 2016

root@Ubuntu:/# cat /etc/timezone 
Europe/London

root@Ubuntu:/# ls -l /etc/localtime 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Mar 11 13:20 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London
```

However, my log files in /var/log are all 9 hrs ahead (Korea time?). E.g

```
root@Ubuntu:/# tail -3 /var/log/auth.log.1

Mar 11 22:27:05 Ubuntu sshd[18170]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=211.99.249.89 
Mar 11 22:27:07 Ubuntu sshd[18170]: Failed password for invalid user cstrike from 211.99.249.89 port 38066 ssh2
Mar 11 22:27:07 Ubuntu sshd[18170]: Connection closed by 211.99.249.89 [preauth]
```

This remains the case even after a `service rsyslog restart` and `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`.

How do I get everything on the same timezone?

Answer (score 9):

I suffered from the same problem and issued the commands `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` and `service rsyslog restart` in succession on a 14.04 server. I then initiated an ssh connection whilst viewing `auth.log` with

```
tail -f /var/log/auth.log
```

Log messages from then on were correct, as may be seen in this snippet

```
Aug 16 09:02:40 myhost sshd[11913]: Accepted publickey ...
Aug 16 09:02:40 myhost sshd[11913]: pam_unix(sshd:session): opened ...
Aug 16 09:02:43 myhost sshd[11913]: pam_unix(sshd:session): closed ...
Aug 16 15:04:45 myhost sshd[12019]: Accepted publickey .... 
Aug 16 15:04:45 myhost sshd[12019]: pam_unix(sshd:session): opened ...
Aug 16 15:05:11 myhost sshd[12019]: pam_unix(sshd:session): closed ...
```

I see you did a tail of `auth.log.1` (an older log file). Making the timezone changes does not modify an existing log file retroactively. Was that the problem perhaps?

Comment: `service rsyslog restart` save my day

Comment: after doing the above steps i still had to restart apache2 for the logs to go to the right timezone:    systemctl restart apache2

Answer (score 0):

(As I answered [elsewhere](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-adjust-the-server-timezone-in-app-platform?comment=191622)) This command did it for me in Ubuntu 22.10:

```
$ sudo timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York
```

Time zone names:

```
$ timedatectl list-timezones | less
```

Confirm:

```
$ timedatectl
           Local time: Sat 2022-11-26 10:52:08 EST
       Universal time: Sat 2022-11-26 15:52:08 UTC
             RTC time: Sat 2022-11-26 15:52:08
            Time zone: America/New_York (EST, -0500)
```

Log files will not show the new timezone until you restart. `sudo apache2ctl restart` did it for the apache logs but to get all the logs (mysql, certbot, etc):

```
$ reboot
```

---

I try not to hate Oracle, I really try. But to get `/var/log/mysql/error.log` to use my timezone setting I had to take this additional step:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/timestamps_system.cnf
```

and put [MTK's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44883646/673991) solution there:

```
[mysqld]
log_timestamps = SYSTEM
```